# Bootstrap table multi select rows and highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap Tables and currently using the `Hoverable Rows` that they offer. I used the table code from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#hoverable-rows and modified it slightly to work with the JS.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically I want to be able to click on a row and it keeps the hover effect. And then when I click it again it will remove the hover. But I want to be able to select multiple rows.

I found some JS and was able to get it to work with only one row being selected..

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

I do not know JS very well and am looking for a way to allow multiple rows to be selected/unselected.

I was able to change the JS to:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And it allowed me to select multiple. But I can't unselect them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("hover")) {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  }
});
```

// for hover class create css code

```
.hover {
  background-color: #8f8f8f;
}
```

I believe that this solution can fix your problem hasClass() check if hover class is exist if it is you will remove it otherwise you will add active class to element and you can changer to hover color whatever you want

Comment: Awesome. Works exactly like I need.

Answer (score 1):

Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

> .toogleClass(className)

```
 $('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });
```